# iphone uiscrollview and uiimageview - setting initial zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I use the following code to load an image into an scroll view. The image always loads at 100% zoom. Is there a way to set it to load to another zoom level, say .37?

I have tried scrollView.zoomScale = .37 but it didnt seem to work

```
UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        self.imageView = tempImage;

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width , imageView.frame.size.height);
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .37;
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        scrollView.delegate = self;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out... I was using scrollView.zoomScale = 0.37; before I loaded the image changed code and it works great.

```
UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
self.imageView = tempImage;

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width , imageView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .37;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.zoomScale = .37;
```

Answer (score 18):

Zooming only works when you implement the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate callback.

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
  return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`zoomScale` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW41) that you can set.

Comment: But take note that as Brodie4598 mentioned that this should be done after the imageView has been added to the scrollView.

Comment: Note also that the delegate's `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` will be called when you set the zoomScale property, so you need to make sure it returns the correct view at that point.

Comment: It is very important what @paul_sns stated. I was having strange behaviour with zooming the scrollview. That is because I set image after setting zoomscale.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue.. 
i used the built in method : scrollViewForImage
This will set the initial zoom to level 5

`[self.scrollViewForImage setZoomScale:5 animated:YES];`

code for minimum zoom level

`self.scrollViewForImage.minimumZoomScale=1;`

code for Maximum Zoom Level

`self.scrollViewForImage.maximumZoomScale=12.0;`

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You must set the initial zoom when the viewwillappear and not when the viewdidload for it too work.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Explain clealy.