# add UIWebView programmatically to UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to be able to add zoom functionality to UIImage and believe the best way is to embed within UIWebview. Would someone be able to help me achieve this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// image
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, IMGSIZE.width, IMGSIZE.height)];
[self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = kITBarTint.CGColor;
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
self.imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
self.imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 10;

[self.controller.view addSubview:self.imageView];

// activity indicator
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(roundf(IMGSIZE.width / 2) + self.imageView.frame.origin.x, roundf(IMGSIZE.height /2) + self.imageView.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
_activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[_activityIndicator setFrame:frame];
[_activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.controller.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];


}
```

Comment: I think using a UIScrollView would be a better approach - see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685161/iphone-uiscrollview-and-uiimageview-setting-initial-zoom)

Comment: How do I use a scrollview to zoom and apply to the code above?

Comment: try my code, it works fine for me!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `viewDidLoad` method,

```
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];
```

Hope this helps!!

And try using a UIScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to Use a UIImageview additionally.

For Local files use file:// as url. you can get a path of a file width:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimage" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

For the Webview simple create a Html Code as String.

```
[webView loadHTMLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

Inside the HTML String you can also use CSS for sizing or positioning!