# Can't get UIScrollview to start zoomed out in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm new to Xcode and have been trying to get a UIScrollview to start zoomed out, i.e. encompassing the whole UIImageview in the content view. From interface builder, I can get it to display the image and scroll. From what I've read, I'll need to do some programming to get it to zoom and scroll, however none of the solutions I've read have worked.

I created the UIScrollview and its content view in interface builder and linked it to ViewController.h. However when I add code like the following, nothing changes:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
self.scrollView.zoomScale = .37;
```

I tried following the instructions in the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685161/iphone-uiscrollview-and-uiimageview-setting-initial-zoom), but I'm not sure how the code needs to change based on the fact that I'm adding it via viewcontroller.h and not instituting it programmatically.

Thanks! I've been stuck on this for a while and can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Your minimumZoomScale isn't small enough. Try setting it to 0.1f;

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
```